# Using python extract from list of string

Tags: python-3.x, list

I have list of string from which i want to extract channel number value with low SIG value.
Below is mt list name "Outlines"

```
Flags: A - active, P - privacy, R - routeros-network, N - nstreme, T - tdma,
W - wds, B - bridge
       ADDRESS           SSID        CHANNEL   SIG   NF SNR RADIO-... ROUTER...
AP     20:B5:C6:F1:B6:B0 INAPHDBD... 5815/2... -78  -60 -18
       52:4F:54:43:4F:44 P2MPRWXX... 5835/20/a -80 -102  22
A      52:41:44:57:49:4E             5835/20/a -86 -102  16
APR  B 4C:5E:0C:BF:EE:6E iBw         5865/2... -75 -102  27 4C5E0C... 6.38.5
A      00:19:70:2C:FD:82 TR6SL5      5835/20/a -86 -102  16
       20:B5:C6:F0:E6:F7             5855/20/a -58 -103  45
```

Below is the code i tried, but didnt know how i can iterate when line starts without blank or any other random value.

```
RSSI = ''
Myindex = [l for l, elem in enumerate (outlines) if 'AP' in elem]
#Myindex = [elem for elem in outlines if 'AP' in elem]


#RSSI =int('nan')
for ind in Myindex:
    newchannel = " ".join(outlines[ind].split()).split(' ')[3]
    newRSSI = " ".join(outlines[ind].split()).split(' ')[4]
    if RSSI < newRSSI or RSSI == '':
        RSSI =newRSSI
        channel = newchannel.split('/')[0]
       
print(channel)
```

Comment: If you have columnar data realise you can splice into a String in Python with the `s[n:m]` syntax https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-index-and-slice-strings-in-python-3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figure out to extract the channel value having lowest SIG value using regex, regex are very power to use specially for a nasty data(list of strings).
i used regex101 . com which makes life easier. below is the code i tried.

```
import re
outlines = """
Flags: A - active, P - privacy, R - routeros-network, N - nstreme, T - tdma,
W - wds, B - bridge
       ADDRESS           SSID        CHANNEL   SIG   NF SNR RADIO-... ROUTER...
AP     20:b5:C6:F1:B6:B0 INAPHDBD... 5815/2... -78  -60 -18
       52:4F:54:43:4F:44 P2MPRWXX... 5835/20/a -80 -102  22
A      52:41:44:57:49:4E             5835/20/a -86 -102  16
APR  B 4C:5E:0C:BF:EE:6E iBw         5865/2... -75 -102  27 4C5E0C... 6.38.5
A      00:19:70:2C:FD:82 TR6SL5      5835/20/a -86 -102  16
       20:b5:C6:F0:E6:F7             5855/20/a -58 -103  45
"""
regex = ".* ([0-9]+)\/[^ ]* ([-+0-9]*)[ ,]*"
        oldsig =''
        if __name__ == '__main__':
​
            for line in outlines:
                s = re.search(regex, line.replace('\r\n',''))
​
                if s:
                    channel = s.group(1)
                    sig = s.group(2)
                    if oldsig < sig or oldsig=='':
                        oldsig = sig
                        nchannel1 = channel
  
            print(nchannel1)
```

Which gives output

```
5835
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get the positions in each line you need to parse from the line that contains `'SIG' and 'CHANNEL'`.

You can loop all lines, extract the positions and convert the SIG to a number and put it into a dictionary of lists of CHANNELS (if 2 have the same SIG and both are lowest).

You can proceed to work with the dictionary data:

```
t = """Flags: A - active, P - privacy, R - routeros-network, N - nstreme, T - tdma,
W - wds, B - bridge
        ADDRESS           SSID        CHANNEL   SIG   NF SNR RADIO-... ROUTER...
AP     20:B5:C6:F1:B6:B0 INAPHDBD... 5815/2... -78  -60 -18
        52:4F:54:43:4F:44 P2MPRWXX... 5835/20/a -80 -102  22
A      52:41:44:57:49:4E             5835/20/a -86 -102  16
APR  B 4C:5E:0C:BF:EE:6E iBw         5865/2... -75 -102  27 4C5E0C... 6.38.5
A      00:19:70:2C:FD:82 TR6SL5      5835/20/a -86 -102  16
        20:B5:C6:F0:E6:F7             5855/20/a -58 -103  45
"""

sigstart = 0
channelstart = 0
data = {}
for line in t.split("\n"):
    # find position of SIG and CHANNEL, ignore everything until we have that
    if sigstart == 0:
        try:
            sigstart = line.index("SIG")
            channelstart = line.index("CHANNEL")
        except ValueError:
            pass
        continue

    # parse line if long enough and has AP in it
    if len(line)>= sigstart+3 and "AP" in line:
        sig = int(line[sigstart:sigstart+3].strip())
        channel = line[channelstart:sigstart].strip()
        # add to dictionary - could use defaultdict if perfomance is an issue
        # but for the example this works just fine
        data.setdefault(sig,[]).append(channel)

# output all parsed data, sorted:
for sig,channel in  sorted(data.items(), key = lambda x:x[0]):
    print(sig, ', '.join(c.split("/")[0] for c in channel))
```

Output:

```
-78 5815  # lowerst, only 1 item
-75 5865
```

The very lowest would be  `sorted(data.items(), key = lambda x:x[0])[0]`.